# Update ListView from BroadcastReceiver OnReceiver()

Tags: java, android, parsing, android-intent

I would like to update a listview from my custom broadcastreceiver. What would be the best way to implement such a feature? Here is my receiver code.
I'm building a messaging app that uses the Parse API. I've tried updating the adapter from the broadcaster,but it keeps force closing.

```
package com.example.datatest;

import java.util.Iterator;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
public class MyCustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG = "MyCustomReceiver";
@Override

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


try {
  String action = intent.getAction();
  String channel = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Channel");
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
  PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
          PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

  // Create Notification using NotificationCompat.Builder
  NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
          context)
          // Set Icon
          .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
          // Set Ticker Message
          .setTicker("New Message")
          // Set Title
          .setContentTitle("MESSAGE")
          // Set Text
          .setContentText("TEST")
          // Add an Action Button below Notification
          .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Action Button", pIntent)
          // Set PendingIntent into Notification
          .setContentIntent(pIntent)
          // Dismiss Notification
          .setAutoCancel(true);

  // Create Notification Manager
  NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) context
          .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  // Build Notification with Notification Manager
  notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());
  Log.d(TAG, "got action " + action + " on channel " + channel + " with:");
  Iterator itr = json.keys();
  while (itr.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String) itr.next();
    Log.d(TAG, "..." + key + " => " + json.getString(key));
  }
} catch (JSONException e) {
  Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
}
 }
}
```

Fixed my issue,I was using unnecessary actions within my BroadcastReciver within the manifest.

Comment: You could create a callback interface, set it in your receiver, makes your ui class implement the methods. and that's it